# Celery signature/delay AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'game_id'

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

First I chain tasks like this

```py
tasks_chain = chain(create_game_folder.si(instance.id))
tasks_chain |= download_game.si(instance.id).set(
            task_id=str(task_id)
        )
```

But I get this error

```
    logger.debug(f"{game_id=}")
AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'game_id'
```

This is how the create folder function starts

```py
@shared_task()
def create_game_folder(game_id):
    logger.info("create_game_folder")
    logger.debug(f"{game_id=}")
    game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
```

Why is it trying to get game_id from UUID? I know that instance.id returns a UUID object but if I do str(instance.id) I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'game_id'`

Is this something .si() or .delay() do in the background and for some reason the stacktrace is showing me the logger line?

Update:

/etc/systemd/system/celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
Requires=django-app.service
After=django-app.service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=david
Group=vboxsf
RuntimeDirectory=celery
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/django-app.com
ExecStart=poetry run celery -A game_manager multi start worker --loglevel="INFO" --concurrency=5
ExecStop=poetry run celery multi stopwait worker --loglevel="INFO"
ExecReload=poetry run celery -A game_manager multi restart worker --loglevel="INFO" --concurrency=5
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

celery config

```
# Celery configuration
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

/etc/systemd/system/django-app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Django app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=david
Group=david
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE"
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/django-app.com
ExecStart=poetry run gunicorn game_manager.wsgi:application --config game_manager/gunicorn_conf.py --reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: When the error is raised? When a task is executed by worker or when you build the task signature? If this error is raised during development could you restart the worker in order to have updated code in worker too?

Comment: In the worker during development, I'm pretty sure I've done systemctl restart celery multiple times and still got the error, now I've done it again and it seems to have ACTUALLY updated the code. Added services files in OP just in case I have something wrong there.

Comment: Could you extend the stack trace when `AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'game_id'` occurs, please?

Comment: Also, it would be good to know what happens to `tasks_chain` later. Do you call `delay`?

Comment: The stacktrace sometimes showed one line as being the problem and sometimes a different one (that apparently had no relation to the error), you were probably right about the worker not having updated code, I could have sworn I had restarted the service multiple times with no luck, so I have no idea why after restarting today again it fixed itself. Yes I did `tasks_chain.delay()` now changed to `transaction.on_commit(lambda: tasks_chain.delay())` due to ATOMIC_REQUESTS being true.

Comment: Let me try to understand. After restarting, is there any problem left to help with?

Comment: If the services files are ok then no, no problems left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it trying to get `game_id` from UUID? I know that `instance.id` returns a `UUID` object, but if I do `str(instance.id)` I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'game_id'`

In your case, it appears that somewhere in your code, in the `download_game` function, or possibly in a function that it calls, there is an attempt to access a `game_id` attribute on an object that is a `UUID` or a `str`. That is what is causing the error.

For instance, if `download_game` is defined something like this:

```py
def download_game(game):
    some_var = game.game_id  # That will throw an error if game is a UUID or str
    # rest of the function
```

You will get the `AttributeError` when you try to call `download_game.si(instance.id)` because `instance.id` is a `UUID` or `str`, not an object with a `game_id` attribute.

---

> you were probably right about the worker not having updated code, I could have sworn I had restarted the service multiple times with no luck

If you have updated the code and restarted the worker, but it seemed like the worker was still running the old version of the code, you need to consider that:

- there might be some delay in the propagation of the code changes, especially if the code is running with a [distributed task queue (Celery)](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/).
- there might be [multiple worker processes running](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/internals/worker.html#internals-the-worker), and while you have restarted one, others might still be running the old version of the code.
- the worker might be picking tasks from the queue that were queued before the code changes, hence the tasks were serialized with the old version of the code.